# Pyramid from an unfolded three-dimensional cube surface

Tags: geometry

It is possible to construct triangular pyramid from standard unfolding of a three-dimensional cube:

[image: cube unfolding]

But I can't find original article (or any other source) where it come from.

Is there such an article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I find it [here (lang ru)](http://www.etudes.ru/ru/etudes/razvertka/).
[image]